# Why won't my return work?

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation, dom

I only just started learning JS like 5-10 minutes ago, I was told by someone to try and create a basic validation feature, however it doesn't seem to work as wanted. It checks if field is empty, that part works. But checking if it's got something in it and carrying on running the code doesn't.

my form:

```
echo '<form action="index.php?action=getHashedText" method="post"     name="formHash">
        <br/><textarea name="text" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Add your text/pharse/word which you want hashing here." autofocus></textarea><br/>
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="return validate();">Hash</button>';
```

function validate():

```
    <script>
    function validate() {
        with (window.document.formHash) {
            if (formHash.text.value === "") {
                    alert('Field is empty!');   
                    return false;
            } else {
                    return true;
            }    
        }  
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You *really* shouldn't be using [`with(){}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).  If you're just learning, you should learn the right way :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are using a button that is not submitting the form anyway (regardless of your js), change this dom:

```
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="return validate();">Hash</button>
```

To this: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rJdkt/)

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Hash" onclick="return validate();" />
```

---

Or you can just add `type="submit"` on your `<button>` (HT @RocketHazmat): [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rJdkt/1/)

```
<button type="submit" name="button" onclick="return validate();">Hash</button>
```

---

Or you can just remove the `type` on your `<button>` all together as the default `type` is `submit` (HT @FabrícioMatté): [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/smerny/rJdkt/2/)

```
<button name="button" onclick="return validate();">Hash</button>
```

---

Also, slightly off topic but I would get in the habit of avoiding putting javascript onclicks directly on your elements. You can create listeners instead: [**addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: Darn it!  I just posted the same answer.  You beat me by 8 seconds!

Comment: Happens to me all the time :P

Comment: You *can* do `<button type="submit"` too ^~^

Comment: I normally only use `<button>` for when I am doing something other than a form submit - but that is good to know.

Comment: @smerny, Initially before I started using JS, I used <input> then for some strange reason I ended up using <button>. Thanks for this anyway! :)

Comment: BTW `<button>`'s default `type` is `submit` (though of course the submit behavior is only applied when the button is inside of a form), so simply removing `type="button"` works too.